# click on submit button - pop-up alert is opened and closed quickly

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd

I have to verify that some fields (input) from a form are mandatory. I let the given field empty and then click on submit button. A pop-up alert with a message is opened. When I automated the test after click on submit button the alert is opened and then closed quickly and I can't switch to alert. Why after click the alert doesn't remain opened?

Using 2 methods: first click the button and second switch to alert. This is not working.

Using one method: when I click the button in the same method that does the switch to alert it works.

```
public void clickContinue()
{
    continueButton.submit();        
}

public String clickAndGetAlertMessage()
{
    //continueButton.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = getDriver().switchTo().alert();
    //alert.accept();

    System.out.println("Alert message: " + alert.getText());
    return alert.getText();
}
```

Is it possible to keep separately these two methods for testing this scenario or I have to use them under a single method?